Neural Network with Genetic Algorithm Connect4
I have created a program that learns how to play connect4 using a neural network and genetic algorithms.
It starts with random weight neural networks, lets every network play against each of the other networks once, chooses the top winning neural networks (the ones that won the most games), breeds and mutates them and creates a new population for the next generation.
It doesn't seem to learn how to play the game well. I thought that maybe my problem is that the fitness score is too much based on the other networks (the 'stupidity' of some of the networks). I mean lets take network A that plays against B,C,D. If B,C,D are really bad it gives a really good fitness score to network A. It also causes the fitness of my first generations to be quite high as if network X just puts always in the same column it wins most game against other 'stupid' network that place the pieces in multiple columns.
How would you tackle this problem?
